# What is wrong with my question so people always downvote when there is one upvote?

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes, up-votes

Currently I am seeing the progess of [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350057/adding-colors-in-cocos2d-for-ios) I have made and I noticed that people are downvoting it without any comment but **only** when there is an upvote.

Is something wrong with my question or this attitude is just normal?

**EDIT**

Ok, maybe it was a coincidence. Although I improved the question with the suggestions I received here people are still downvoting. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: Why do you think people are down-voting simply because there is an up-vote? There are a lot of people on StackOverflow with various reasons to judge whether a question is useful or not. I would be careful about making any assumptions based on what you are observing - especially with a grand total sample size of two upvotes and two downvotes - they are almost certainly just coincidences.

Comment: Your question looked pretty good to me.  Seems like you were not asking for some running code but just a pointer to the API set you'd need to use.   I guess some folks don't realize that you can get a nudge in the right direction at any stage in the development process.

Comment: Those coincidences happened again. But you are right. Maybe I am being kinda paranoid. However, since there are a lot of people in the StackOverflow with various reasons to judge whether a question is useful or not it could be nice for those people to at least provide their reason so you could improve. Actually, when someone comes here to ask anything they might want the answer they are looking for so they have no problem to edit their question with suggestions (we are here to improve, right?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your example question, it's not terrible, but it's also not immediately clear what you tried. You did mention trying using different blend modes, but it might not be clear to everyone what that means, or what *specifically* you did to try those blend modes.

I'm not an iOS expert, but surely there must be code you're using? If so, you should edit your post and include it. This helps people who might answer have a starting point and also be sure not to suggest something you've already tried.

It's discouraging when you've researched a problem and posted a well-written answer only to have the op exclaim "no i try that alredy and it dont work!!"

So, to be sure your question doesn't get a downvote, make sure you show examples of what you tried and even explain what the output was that you were getting that was incorrect.

With that said, I didn't downvote, so I can't really read the minds of those who did. But I'm certain that this is one reason why someone might downvote or even vote to close. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It makes sense. I believe that I tried to be as simple and direct as I could but I have to give you reason. Someone might answer (like actually happened, I did tried the website that LearnCocos2D presented) and then I say "I have done that" and is kinda annoying. Thanks for your constructive answer.

Answer (score 5):

After reading the question (and I am also pointing out that I am not familiar with iOS in any way), you might want to edit it somewhat - as in the current reading - while there isn't anything that just out like a sore thumb, it also reads a bit like *I want to do this magically without really having to do anything... anyone?*

Now, given that you went to the trouble of using a nice image in your question to illustrate it, I am sure that it wasn't the way you meant to ask it - but if you include things like *but I can't get the effect I want* then you really should go out of your way to explain in detail what you have tried, and how the outcome differed from the result that you wanted.

People can and do downvote questions because they are vague, but people also downvote questions that appear to be vague. Remember, in asking a great question, put all the information into the question that will be required to answer it. And it really never, ever hurts to post some code in a question like this - perhaps a function param was a digit off, perhaps you should be using a different function - who knows or can pinpoint a problem without seeing it?

I might be a little harsh in this answer, but I am simply pointing out the reasons that people *might* be thinking and then downvoting. Looking at it, I would have asked for clarification on some points and probably not downvoted, but I also hardly *ever* downvote.

Comment: You weren't harsh at all. Thanks for your answer. In my questions I always try to be simple since the ones that I see with most votes (and consequently more detailed answers) are the ones that say "How can I do this?". 1-2 lines. That simple. But I guess when we are doing specific answers to a specific case we can't be like that. Can't accept both answers, but both are good. Going to accept the one with most votes. Thanks.